# Why does CO2 diffuse through a butyl rubber membrane more readily than air?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am a cyclist, and not a chemist. When I or my cycling buddies get a flat tire out on the road, after removing the offending sharp object (if any) remaining in the tire, we will typically replace the punctured butyl rubber inner tube with a new one, and then inflate the tire using a $\ce{CO2}$ cartridge.

Inflating the tire in this way takes less than a second to bring the pressure up to 120 psi. At home, naturally, we fill our tires with air rather than a $\ce{CO2}$ cartridge, using a floor pump.

When we fill our tire with an air pump the tire remains inflated for several days. But after filling it with $\ce{CO2}$, the tire is severely flat again by the next morning. $\ce{CO2}$ clearly diffuses through the butyl membrane very much more rapidly than air, even though $\ce{CO2}$ is a larger molecule than either $\ce{N2}$ or $\ce{O2}$. Is it the shape of the molecule? Or its chemical properties?

Comment: Second link to lecture notes can be found at Way back Machine or similar metacrawlers. https://web.archive.org/web/20190712202752/http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jae1001/cus/teaching/materials/M6_lecture_6.pdf

Answer (score 10):

The permeability of a gas through rubber depends mainly on its [diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_diffusivity) and [solubility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility) in rubber.

$\ce{CO2}$ has a significantly higher solubility in rubber than $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{N2}$, whereas the diffusion coefficients differ not that much.

> [image]
> Source: [[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712202752/http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jae1001/cus/teaching/materials/M6_lecture_6.pdf)].

The result is that carbon dioxide passes ordinary rubber about 5 times faster than oxygen and about 15 times faster than nitrogen[[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712202752/http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jae1001/cus/teaching/materials/M6_lecture_6.pdf), [2](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ScientificPapers/nbsscientificpaper387vol16p327_A2b.pdf)].

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer and references. Too bad nitrogen cartridges aren't available for cyclists!

Comment: @R.Gold please mark aventurins answer as "accepted"  - that is the way to pay tribute for good answers here ;-)

Comment: @datenheim R Gold has biked on, last seen 2016. It’s a great answer, I agree (as I upvote…).

Comment: Carry an attachable bike pump  or buy one of the new battery powered minipumps.