What type of gas will stay in a latex balloon the longest – regular air, helium, and argon? Why?
I filled up balloons with the different gases and measured their circumference every 12 hours. By the end of the 96-hour period, the regular air balloons had decreased by only 1.8%; the helium balloons decreased by 25.9%; and the argon balloons decreased by 22.3%. Regular air stayed in the latex balloon the longest, only decreasing by 1.2cm in circumference.
One possible answer is the 'van der Waals force'. What is that?

Air contains two gases at noticeable amount. These have slower diffusion inside the latex, obviously. Maybe because of larger molecules or stronger van der Waals force.

What is the 'van der Waals' force?

Grahams Law is based on the Ideal Gas Law where molecules are dimensionless and do not interact with the pinholes. Real gases have sizes and shapes and solubilities in other materials. Congrats on the experimental data. Please explain your question or thinking.

It may be more complex than simple diffusion would suggest. Gas solubility in rubber may matter more: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/54826/81

BTW, an extreme case of departure from expectations is the diffusion of hydrogen through palladium -- it is quite rapid through that solid metal! https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0376738812005996 This is used to purify H2, with just about everything else left on the other side.

Then there is diffusion of SF6 into tennis balls making them rupture…
